# Can´t save view with function (GCP)

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I´m working with BIGQUERY trying to produce a view using a query with a Function (This is an example not the query itself)

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION validate_rut(s string)

RETURNS string

AS (

if(length(s) = 10 or length(s) = 12 , left(regexp_replace(s, r'[.-]', ''), 8)

, if(length(s) = 11 or length(s) = 9, left(regexp_replace(s, r'[.-]', ''), 7)

, null)

)

);

select rut, validate_rut(rut)

from (select '11.111.111-8' rut union all

select '11111111-8' union all

select '2.222.222-9' union all

select '2222222-9'union all

select '33333333' union all

select '7777777'

)

The problem is that when I try to save the query as a view I get this message.

"No support For create Temporary Function statements inside views"

This is the first time i´m trying to do something like this.

Thank You.

Comment: create permanent udf instead?!

Comment: hello, when i do it like this. 
"CREATE TEMP FUNCTION validate_rut(s string)" i don´t get an error in bigquery, but if i do it like this "CREATE FUNCTION validate_rut(s string)"  i got : "Routine "validate_rut" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.routine)." i don´t know how to solve it, there are supposed to be the same thing for what i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your function as permanant udf with the following syntax :

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `my_project.my_dataset.validate_rut`(s string)

RETURNS string
AS (
if(length(s) = 10 or length(s) = 12 , left(regexp_replace(s, r'[.-]', ''), 8)
, if(length(s) = 11 or length(s) = 9, left(regexp_replace(s, r'[.-]', ''), 7)
, null)
)
);
```

In this example your permanent `udf` is created on an existing `Bigquery` `dataset` called `my_dataset`.

Then you can query your function as expected with the following syntax :

```sql
select rut, `my_project.my_dataset.validate_rut`(rut)
from (select '11.111.111-8' rut union all
select '11111111-8' union all
select '2.222.222-9' union all
select '2222222-9'union all
select '33333333' union all
select '7777777'
);
```

Comment: Thank you Mazlum, I´m in a learning path at the moment so any help is welcome, the function works perfectly

Comment: Cool :), may you upvote the answer and mark it as resolved, to help new comers on this topic ?